# How can I print each value in a list without shortening the list in python?

Tags: python, list

What I am trying to do is this:

```
Str = "yes"
lst = ["e1", "e2", "e3", "y1", "y2", "y3", "s1", "s2", "s3"]
```

I want to be able to print out each item in the list that has a character in Str. So for example I want it to return this:

```
["y1", "y2", "y3", "e1", "e2", "e3", "s1", "s2", "s3"]
```

Since that is the order of Str. I have this so far:

```
newlst = []
while lst != []:
if Str[0] in text[0]:
    newlst += text[0]
    lst = lst[1:]
    Str = Str[1:]
else:
   lst = lst[1:]
```

My problem is that it only gives me:

```
["y1", "y2", "y3"]
```

It's because the list is now []. Is there any way to do this without shortening the list? So keeping it the same but just extracting the values in list that contain Str[n]?

Comment: quote your strings please.

Comment: Do you want each item in the list to print out every time, if the character appears more than once in the string?

Comment: Yes essentially.

Answer (score 1):

Using list comrehension, I compared with the first item

```
[x for item in Str for x in list if x[0] in item]
```

Output :

```
['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'e1', 'e2', 'e3', 's1', 's2', 's3']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `sort` your initial list based on where the letters are in `my_str` like so:

```
my_str = "yes"
my_list = ['e1', 'e2', 'e3', 'y1', 'y2', 'y3', 's1', 's2', 's3']

res = sorted(my_list, key= lambda x: my_str.find(x[0]))
print(res)  # -> ['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'e1', 'e2', 'e3', 's1', 's2', 's3']
```

---

**NOTES**

1. `'y2'` appears after `'y1'` only because that is the order in the original list (`my_list`). If you want the numbers to act as *tie-brakers*, the code would have to be modified a bit.
2. Do not use Python built-in names like `str` and `list`. You are overriding functions that you might need later on.

---

```
print('yes'.find('y'))   # -> 0  |
print('yes'.find('e'))   # -> 1  | -> values used by the sorting (smallest to largest)!
print('yes'.find('s'))   # -> 2  |
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also group the strings with a dictionary, easier with a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_string = "yes"
my_list = ["e1", "e2", "e3", "y1", "y2", "y3", "s1", "s2", "s3"]

d = defaultdict(list)
for string in my_list:
    key = string[0]
    d[key].append(string)

>>> print(dict(d))
{'e': ['e1', 'e2', 'e3'], 's': ['s1', 's2', 's3'], 'y': ['y1', 'y2', 'y3']}
```

Then simply run through the ordering of `my_string` and concatenate the resulting lists with [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> lsts = [d[key] for key in my_string]
>>> print(lsts)
[['y1', 'y2', 'y3'], ['e1', 'e2', 'e3'], ['s1', 's2', 's3']]
>>> print(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(lsts)))
['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'e1', 'e2', 'e3', 's1', 's2', 's3']
```

Or:

```
>>> print([item for sublist in lsts for item in sublist])
['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'e1', 'e2', 'e3', 's1', 's2', 's3']
```